# Color between 2 lines

Tags: pine-script

I use MACD and I would like :

between the two lines `macd_color` and `signal_color` :

- green color when macd is above signal
- red color when macd is below signal

  ```
  study(title="MACD V5", shorttitle="MACD V5")
  source = close
  useCurrentRes = input(true, title="Use Current Chart Resolution?")
  resCustom = input(title="Use Different Timeframe? Uncheck Box Above", type=resolution, 
  defval="60")
  smd = input(true, title="Show MacD & Signal Line? Also Turn Off Dots Below")
  sd = input(true, title="Show Dots When MacD Crosses Signal Line?")
  sh = input(true, title="Show Histogram?")
  macd_colorChange = input(true,title="Change MacD Line Color-Signal Line Cross?")
  hist_colorChange = input(true,title="MacD Histogram 4 Colors?")

  res = useCurrentRes ? period : resCustom

  fastLength = input(12, minval=1), slowLength=input(26,minval=1)
  signalLength=input(9,minval=1)

  fastMA = ema(source, fastLength)
  slowMA = ema(source, slowLength)

  macd = fastMA - slowMA
  signal = sma(macd, signalLength)
  hist = macd - signal

  outMacD = security(tickerid, res, macd)
  outSignal = security(tickerid, res, signal)
  outHist = security(tickerid, res, hist)

  histA_IsUp = outHist > outHist[1] and outHist > 0
  histA_IsDown = outHist < outHist[1] and outHist > 0
  histB_IsDown = outHist < outHist[1] and outHist <= 0
  histB_IsUp = outHist > outHist[1] and outHist <= 0

  //MacD Color Definitions
  macd_IsAbove = outMacD >= outSignal
  macd_IsBelow = outMacD < outSignal

  plot_color = hist_colorChange ? histA_IsUp ? aqua : histA_IsDown ? blue : histB_IsDown ? red : 
  histB_IsUp ? maroon :yellow :gray
  macd_color = macd_colorChange ? macd_IsAbove ? lime : red : red
  signal_color = macd_colorChange ? macd_IsAbove ? yellow : yellow : lime

  circleYPosition = outSignal

  plot(smd and outMacD ? outMacD : na, title="MACD", color=macd_color, linewidth=2)
  plot(smd and outSignal ? outSignal : na, title="Signal Line", color=signal_color, style=line 
  ,linewidth=2)
  plot(sh and outHist ? outHist : na, title="Histogram", color=plot_color, style=histogram, 
  linewidth=4)
  plot(sd and cross(outMacD, outSignal) ? circleYPosition : na, title="Cross", style=circles, 
  linewidth=3, color=macd_color)
  hline(0, '0 Line', linestyle=solid, linewidth=2, color=white)
  band1 = hline(25, "Upper Band", color=#ff0000)
  band0 = hline(-25, "Lower Band", color=#00ff0a)
  ```

I don't know how to do it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `fill()` function for this.

```
fill_color = outMacD > outSignal ? green : red

p_macd = plot(smd and outMacD ? outMacD : na, title="MACD", color=macd_color, linewidth=2)
p_sig = plot(smd and outSignal ? outSignal : na, title="Signal Line", color=signal_color, style=line ,linewidth=2)
fill(p_macd, p_sig, fill_color, 85)
```

[image]